# Deduplicate rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]
I got a USER table ,i need to deduplicate records when the field age and name is equal and within 5 minutes keep the earliest record :
 i got sql like this ,but is don't work somehow:

```
SELECT *
FROM user u1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM user u2 
                  WHERE u2.name = u1.name AND u2.age = u1.age
                    AND u2.created_at > u1.created_at - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```

Comment: show your expected output in tabular form.

Comment: What database are you actually using. The answer will be different for each one selected.

Comment: my datebase is mysql

Comment: I wound use unique key for (name, age) and in MySQL you can use replace instead insert ( basically it deletes and inserts data in case there is a collision on a key )

Answer (score 0):

We could try phrasing the logic as deleting any record for which we can find another record by the same age and name, with a create time within 5 minutes of the record being considered for deletion.

```
DELETE
FROM user u1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user u2
              WHERE u2.age = u1.age AND u2.name = u1.name AND
                    TIMEDIFF(t2.create_time, t1.create_time) < '00:05:00');
```

This assumes that you actually want to remove the duplicate records.  If you just want to select, use the logic provided by @Nick which is very similar to my delete query.